# Writing singly Linked List class from scratch - remove, indexOf methods not working

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, indexof

I am writing the singly linked list class from scratch but somewhere my remove at an index and likely indexOf methods are not working.

```
    public E remove(int index){
    if(index < 0 || index > size-1)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("IndexOutOfBounds");

    if(index == 0) {
        E temp1 = head.data;
        Node temp2 = head.next;
        head.next = null;
        head = temp2;
        return temp1;
    }

    Node<E> hopper = getNode(index-1);
    Node<E> toRemove = hopper.next;

    E temp = toRemove.data;
    hopper.next = hopper.next.next;
    toRemove.data = null;
    toRemove.next = null;
    return temp;
}
```

For remove, I suspect there is a fringe case or some logical error somewhere. In my JUnit tester, it appears to not remove anything at all. And as for indexOf:

```
    public int indexOf(Object o){
    if(o == null) {
        Node<E> hopper = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
            if(hopper.data == o)
                return i;
            hopper = hopper.next;
    }}

    else {
        Node<E> hopper = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
            if(hopper.data.equals(o))
                return i;
            hopper = hopper.next;
            }}

    return -1;
}
```

In my JUnit tester, contains does not work and that method literally just calls indexOf to do the search.

I can provide any additional code if needed. If someone could help explain where I am going wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: In `indexOf`, `for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {` should be `i < size`, no?

Comment: (Also, `Objects.equals(o, hopper.data)` would allow you to not have to handle null and non-null cases separately).

Comment: (You should also note that `hopper.data.equals(o)` would fail with a NPE if `hopper.data` is null - presumably a possibility if you check for a value equal to null. `Objects.equals` avoids this too.)

Comment: Just tried to change the for loop statements to size and the for loops would then never terminate for some reason